# ¿Cómo hacer la curva de Hilbert en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

¿Cómo hacer la **[curva de Hilbert](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curva_de_Hilbert)** en Java? ¿Cuál es la complejidad? ¿El código?

Todo en general a como hacer ese fractal recursivo.

```
public static void curva(Graphics papel, int altura, int anchura, int size, int n){
    int x = anchura / 2;
    int y = altura /2;

    int x0 = x - size/2;
    int y0 = y - size/2;
    int x1 = x + size/2;
    int y1 = y + size/2;

    papel.drawLine(x0, y0, x0, y1);
    papel.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y0);
    papel.drawLine(x1, y0, x1, y1);

    curva(papel,x0,y0, size/2,n-1);
    curva(papel,x0,y1,size/2,n-1);
    curva(papel,x1,y0,size/2,n-1);
    curva(papel,x1,y1,size/2,n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto es computacion grafica, un mundo maravilloso, si quieres aprender mas deberias leer algun libro de geometria computacional, te impresionaras con el producto punto de calculo

volviendo al tema:

```
Codigo 1 (Principal.java):

package CurvaHilbert;

public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int x, y, depth, size;

    public Principal() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);// Centrar pantalla
    }

    private void initComponents() { ... }// Codigo generado automaticamente                        

    private void jButtonIniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){           
        Dibujo.Dibujar(
                jPanel1.getGraphics(),
                x = jPanel1.getWidth() / 2,
                y = jPanel1.getHeight() / 2,
                depth = 4,
                size = jPanel1.getHeight() / 2);
    }                                              

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Principal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonIniciar;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}


Codigo 2 (Dibujo.java):

package CurvaHilbert;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Dibujo {

    public static void Dibujar(Graphics g, int x, int y, int n, int size) {
        if (n == 0) return;
        int x0 = x - size / 2;
        int x1 = x + size / 2;
        int y0 = y - size / 2;
        int y1 = y + size / 2;
        g.drawLine(x0, y0, x0, y1);
        g.drawLine(x1, y0, x1, y1);
        g.drawLine(x0, y, x1, y);
        Dibujar(g, x0, y0, n - 1, size / 2);
        Dibujar(g, x0, y1, n - 1, size / 2);
        Dibujar(g, x1, y0, n - 1, size / 2);
        Dibujar(g, x1, y1, n - 1, size / 2);
    }

}
```

espero te sirva...